# fb graph api group feed on specific type only

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

[https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/FB_GROUP_ID/feed?fields=attachments{title,media,subattachments,type,url},type,created_time,description,message,message_tags&limit=10&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN](http://EAABmSZBW6IbkBAPWVQOr9hwgrWxaObgOvqFUJYKoELeUg8MZCmVFlvQP4rnF2vay3BQM9wzUXTjkbQ4Ri5VdunhMscvr19vmUCYkqtLsPXEuYlwuqtrf729CFaLB4iknNlNm4UpdUwrmfNMOv61gsy32uPBS8ZD)

this reruns me all types (`status`, `photo`, `video`, `link`) of feeds

can I make request to have only specified type like `photo` feeds or `video` feeds
actually its `attachments` and `sub-attachments` also have type fields, I am interested to also check `attachments` and `sub-attachments`, return that too if their type is equal to provided type

I want to have 3 arrays

1. textual feeds
2. images
3. videos

Comment: That’s not possible, the API does not offer any such filtering. You’ll have to do it on your end.

Comment: Ok thank you. I hv already managed it

Comment: Can u please look at my another question getting source of videos https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786160/fb-graph-api-get-video-source-in-group-feed